# current_user.try(:admin?) not working in rails (using devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, admin

I am using devise for user authentication. I made an admin role by following the option 2 of [this website](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role).
What I wanted to do was that a person should get an extra link to work on Making the game if he/she signs in as the admin.

Now even though I have made an admin role(I think I do) but I still can't use the option:

```
current_user(:admin?)
```

My code for it is:

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
<li><%= link_tp "Make Game", root_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

I have also tried:

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
```

But still it's not working.

```
rake db:migrate
```

leads to these errors

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: admin: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "admin" boolean DEFAULT
```

db/schema.rb

```
 create_table "levels", :force => true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "profile_name"
t.string   "college_name"
t.string   "email",                  :default => "",    :null => false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "",    :null => false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                                :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",                                :null => false
t.string   "provider"
t.string   "uid"
t.boolean  "admin",                  :default => false
end

add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name =>     "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

Comment: do you see the column 'admin' in users table?

Comment: @emaillenin  `t.boolean  "admin",   :default => false` this is there in my user table. If this is what you mean

Comment: goto rails console. and try `u = User.find(1)` and `u.try(:admin?)`

Comment: @emaillenin I had already deleted the user data using `User.delete_all`. Now if I am adding a new user then he is automatically getting the id = 6 so the first command would obviously not work. Also I am getting `nil` on writing `u.try(:admin?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was stupid of me. What I should have done was to write:

```
user=User.create(:email =>"test@test.com", :password =>"password")
```

I did the above correct but what I didn't do was add the following lines after it:

```
user.admin = true
user.save!
```

Thanks @Rich Peck for all your help

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role#wiki-option-2---adding-an-admin-attribute) won't handle the admin options itself

You'll have to manage the admin part manually (either add an `admin` boolean column to your `users` table, or create a method to handle it):

---

**Column**

As mentioned in the comments, you'll be better adding an `admin` column / attribute to your `users` table. The [Devise github Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role#wiki-option-2---adding-an-admin-attribute) actually talks about this too:

```
#cmd
rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean

#db/migrate/your_migration.rb
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :admin
  end
end
```

This adds the admin attribute as boolean, which means you'll either be `true` or `false`. You can then use your `current_user.try(:admin?)` code to test the attribute for your user

---

**Method**

You also mentioned about `current_user.admin?`

Although the Devise wiki recommends using this, I'd suggest it's an [instance method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) which means you'll have to define it in the `user` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def admin?
        # logic to determine if user is admin
    end
end
```

Comment: I had already added the admin attribute as stated on their wiki page but it's not working. Also I defined it in the user model but still no luck. Is it necessary to add another gem to make it work like cancan?

Comment: Have you restarted your server after the migration?

Comment: So I tried to do `rake db:migrate` and this is what I am getting `SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: admin: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "admin" boolean DEFAULT` I guess this is the root of all my problems?

Comment: Maybe - have you got your schema available for us to see?

Comment: I have edited the main question to include code from my schema.rb

Comment: Okay thanks - considering you have an admin column already, remove all the code from your migration file (apart from the class declaration) and run the migration again (so nothing happens to DB). This will allow us to fix the issue. It's either going to be a Devise or instance method issue I think, but we'll need to play with it a bit more to find out!!

Comment: Well I got rake db:migrate working. I added the code again to migration and rake db:migrate is still working. I added in a user with  `admin => true` and the chosen email address and password but its still not working

Comment: Can you post the specific error? Is it still `no method` error? Can you put your app on Github???

Comment: What is the logic to determine if a user is admin?

Answer (score 0):

Defining roles is not a part of devise gem you need to use rolify or simple roles kind of gems for this task.

https://github.com/EppO/rolify